# Saving a SoundFile from a Button to App.Config

Tags: c#, app-config, wav

I already have the key called "Alert_Sound_File" in my `App.Config` that looks like this:

```
<setting name="Alert_Sound_File" serializeAs="String">
<value />
</setting>
```

This is what my button looks like:

```
public OpenFileDialog dialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();
private void browseSoundToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DialogResult result = dialog1.ShowDialog();
        dialog1.Title = "Browse to find sound file to play first sound";
        dialog1.InitialDirectory = @"c:\";
        dialog1.Filter = "Wav Files (*.wav)|*.wav";
        dialog1.FilterIndex = 2;
        dialog1.RestoreDirectory = true;

        Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        AppSettingsSection app = config.AppSettings;
        app.Settings["Alert_Sound_File"].Value = dialog1.FileName;
        config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
    }
```

The current error I get is:

> "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

But `dialog1.FileName` is set in the button, how am I getting a null value returned?

I have even tried this to test & this does not save into my `App.Config`:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
AppSettingsSection app = config.AppSettings;
app.Settings.Add("y", "this is Y");
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

**UPDATE:** I have added

```
  <appSettings>
<add key="Alert_Sound_File" value="" />
<add key="Error_Sound_File" value="" />
```

To my App.Config file and have this in my button:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
        AppSettingsSection app = config.AppSettings;
        if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            app.Settings["Alert_Sound_File"].Value = dialog1.FileName;
            config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
        }
```

The result is that I do not get the Object reference error anymore but the sound file is not being added to the App.Config file. But I do not get any errors!

Comment: are you getting the exception when you try to get 'dialog1.FileName' value?

Comment: yes @lem2802 not sure why since it comes right after the user selects a file?

Answer (score 0):

please try that in order to be sure that you've selected a file before:

```
if (result == DialogResult.OK) {
    app.Settings["Alert_Sound_File"].Value = dialog1.FileName;
    config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change your app.config file to:

```
<configuration>
   <appSettings>
      <add key="Alert_Sound_File" value="" />
   </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

And you need check dialog result as wrotes at previous post, because if user click cancel field is erased(maybe it really needed?).

For saving you need call save method after modified setting value:

```
config.Save(ConfigurationSaveMode.Modified);
```

Comment: I stopped getting the error for Null but it is not saving in App.Config - I really have no idea whats wrong

Comment: @Havoux Can you try without result var checking?